# How to use the internal drive on my iMac for Time Machine backups

Tags: mac, time-machine, imac

I have an iMac that came with an internal hard drive. The performance sucked so I added an external SSD drive that it boots from.

I would like to use the internal drive for Time Machine backups but it doesn't show up as an option when I start up Time Machine. How can I make this work?

me@my-iMac ~ % mount

/dev/disk3s5s1 on / (apfs, sealed, local, read-only, journaled)

devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)

/dev/disk3s4 on /System/Volumes/VM (apfs, local, noexec, journaled, noatime, nobrowse)

/dev/disk3s2 on /System/Volumes/Preboot (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

/dev/disk3s6 on /System/Volumes/Update (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

/dev/disk3s1 on /System/Volumes/Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

map auto_home on /System/Volumes/Data/home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)

/dev/disk1s1 on /Volumes/Macintosh HD (apfs, local, read-only, journaled)

/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Macintosh HD - Data (apfs, local, journaled, nobrowse)

Comment: Have you researched this issue?

Comment: Yes but I was afraid I might erase my internal disk.

It turned out to be easy and relatively foolproof. I did not have to break out my rusty command line skills.

I used Disk Utility:

Partitioned the hard drive into the bootable partition and the backup partition

I used time machine to backup the data. I am also keeping another backup on a removable drive which I will store separately. Backing up to two devices was easy.

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be easy and relatively foolproof.

I used Disk Utility: Partitioned the hard drive into the bootable partition and the backup partition I used time machine to backup the data. I am also keeping another backup on a removable drive which I will store separately. Backing up to two devices was easy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).